# How to solve the page refresh issue in Yii?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I have a page where we can change our profile picture just like in twitter. But when I change the profile picture, the image is not refreshed. I have used the same controller to change and  render the page. I need to hit F5 button to see the image has been changed.

For Instance: the page is setting/profile, when we save the image the same controller/action is called and the same view is rendered but the image does not refresh.

How do I get this thing work? I have tried javascript, tried redirect nothing seem to work. I can only see it work while hitting F5 button manually.

Any suggestion or solution is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Add a cachebusting query string to the image URL, such as `image.png?_=<current_timestamp>`.

Comment: I kinda understand the idea but still could not get the clear vision on how to implement that. If you don't mind, could you please elaborate a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example you could use in your view.

```
echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/images/profile_pic$user_id.png?_=".time(), 'Profile Pic');
```